# Remove some text after the price in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In Woocommerce, I would like to change the text after the price on my single product pages. There is no class or id associated with this text and do not know which folder it is in:

```
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">35.00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span> Prix hors taxes</p>
```

Does somebody have an idea? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please edit your question by adding more details about your problem and provide code example of what you have tried so far

Comment: **To the reviews community:** Kindly, but this question **is not too broad** and provide everything needed in the question itself, even if it doesn't provide some hooked function code… Here the OP has searched and tried, but didn't find the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove **" Prix hors taxes"** suffix from displayed prices, try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_get_price_html_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_price_html_callback( $price, $product ) {
    return str_replace( __('Prix hors taxes'), '', $price );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

---

Or the same targeting only single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_get_price_html_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_price_html_callback( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_product() )
        $price = str_replace( __('Prix hors taxes'), '', $price );

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much Loic it works perfectly ;-)

Comment: Sorry 
Sorry I can not find the "reopen" link. Why do I have to press this button?

Comment: I only have these choices under my question: share edit delete flag.
I do not see "reopen".
Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @LaurentDore So may be you don't have enough reputation for that… sorry.